# Mass spring system with method of Verlet (1d)

Tags: python, physics

For my home work I have to make a mass spring system (eventually 2d) but I'm trying 1d first). But I can't get it to work, please help me. We have to use the method of Verlet and we have to implement the following function in python. Is my code wrong? And how can I do it best?

Formula: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oi4MVOyTPvMLqZ35zFtQTgPlxNNrCHZy

```
def verlet():
    result = 2 * py[0]  # 2y(ti)
    result -= py_prev[0]    # - y(ti - dt)
    result += (GRAVITATION + (-Ks * (py[0] - py_prev[0]))) / MASS
    py_prev[0] = py[0]
    py[0] = result/20
```

Answer (score 0):

How have you defined the variables? Could you include your entire program?

If all variables are defined the code runs.

Looking at your code, I don't see how you have calculated the last term in the formula.

```
result += (GRAVITATION + (-Ks * (py[0] - py_prev[0]))) / MASS
```

You need to define the time difference between two points. (This is not py[0] - py_prev[0], this is the height difference). 
I think the last term in the formula can be calculated like this:

```
result -= delta_t**2 * py[0]
```

Later on, you are going to need to use a for loop (or even better arrays, but a for loop is easier) to save the position of the oscillator at each time point.